# mmap function for arrays of data

Tags: c, unix, double, mmap

Suppose that you have a binary file. It consists of double's. Its size is enough small to be put in the memory. How to read all of these numbers by using    `mmap`    function?
I have tried to dereference output pointer. But it is only the first element of data. To use loop it's non-trivial how to control the quantity of the elements of the array.

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { // we get filename as an argument from the command line
    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR, 0777);
    size_t size = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
    double m = 0;
    int cnt = 0; // counter of doubles
    void* mp = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (mp == MAP_FAILED)
        return 1;
    double* data = mp;
    m += *data; // we want to count the sum of these doubles
    ++cnt;
    int ump_res = munmap(mp, sizeof(double));
    if (ump_res < sizeof(double))
        return 1;
    printf("%a\n", (m / (double)cnt)); // we output the average number of these doubles
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect that in    `stdout`    we will get the average of all doubles in the file, which name is give in    `argv[1]`    .

Comment: What is `unmap()`? I only know `munmap()`. What is `cnt`? From my PoV you get the average of the first number in the file, which is the first number. You do not loop over all numbers in the file.

Comment: What is SIZE here? It may contain the solution. And unsure that this is a very good use case for memory mapped files, because if would be trivial with `fread`.

Comment: `m += *data; // we want to count the sum of these doubles` then you need to sum the doubles `for (i = 0; i < size/sizeof(double); ++i) sum += data[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to cast    `void*`    to    `double*`    .Then you may iterate and handle elements:

```c
void* mp = mmap(0, length, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (mp == MAP_FAILED) {
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    double* data = (double*)mp;
    size_t cnt = length / sizeof(double);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) {
        m += data[i];
    }
```

Hope you'll find it helpful.